# accessing nested objects with a for in loop

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, for-in-loop

Within javascript, I am trying to print the values from a few objects listed in an array in an object. The question has to do with drilling into objects/arrays with a for in loop. More specifically I'd like to avoid using a for loop if possible (I just learned for/in and am trying to understand it well)

The object looks like this:

```
var users = {
  'Students': [ 
    { first_name:  'Michael', last_name : 'Jordan'  },
    { first_name : 'John',    last_name : 'Rosales' },
    { first_name : 'Mark',    last_name : 'Guillen' },
    { first_name : 'KB',      last_name : 'Tonel'   }
  ],
  'Instructors': [
    { first_name : 'Michael', last_name : 'Jackson' },
    { first_name : 'Martin',  last_name : 'Puryear' }
  ]
};
```

**How could i write a function that returns all of the names burried in this object?** Id like to console log:

```
Students
1 - MICHAEL JORDAN
2 - JOHN ROSALES
3 - MARK GUILLEN
4 - KB TONEL
Instructors
1 - MICHAEL JACKSON
2 - MARTIN PURYEAR
```

Ive tried writing a couple for/in loops but I keep getting unexpected results. *Thanks in advance for taking a look at this.*

Comment: What sort of "couple for/in loops"? What manner of "unexpected results"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can break a problem like this into smaller parts. First, how to we get at the individual elements of your map?

```
for (var key in users) {
   console.log(key);
}
```

logs:

```
students
teachers
```

So now we can get at the members of `users` one at a time, inside that loop:

```
var userArray = users[key];
```

That extracts an array each time. Now you can loop through the array, by adding this *inside the loop we already have*:

```
for(var i in userArray) {
    console.log(userArray[i]);
}
```

That prints out individual items from your list, e.g. `{first_name:  'Michael', last_name : 'Jordan'}`

Now you can print it in a different way.

```
 var item = userArray[i];
 console.log(i + ' ' + item[first_name] + ' ' + item[last_name]);
```

Put all these pieces together and you are very close to your goal (You just need to uppercase -- Google it!)

So we have everything we need to achieve in Javascript, what this pseudocode sums up:

```
for each type of user in "users"
   for each user record in the list
       print the index, firstname and lastname
   end
end
```

You can make this tidier by extracting the inner loop into a function of its own. You can do it in more advanced ways by using functional programming constructs like `array.map()` to translate one array into another. But the pieces above are good "beginners' way" to tackle the problem.

Comment: This helped big time, thank you so much! I was tetering on the edge an answer and this response was the appropriate amount of hand holding to get me there.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to extract the names from the arrays:

```js
function getNames(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(o, i) { // is the object, i is the index in the array
    return (i + 1) + ' - ' + o.first_name + ' ' + o.last_name;
  });
}

var users = {
 'Students': [ 
     {first_name:  'Michael', last_name : 'Jordan'},
     {first_name : 'John', last_name : 'Rosales'},
     {first_name : 'Mark', last_name : 'Guillen'},
     {first_name : 'KB', last_name : 'Tonel'}
  ],
 'Instructors': [
     {first_name : 'Michael', last_name : 'Jackson'},
     {first_name : 'Martin', last_name : 'Puryear'}
  ]
 };

var students = getNames(users.Students);

var instructors = getNames(users.Instructors);

console.log('Students\n', students);
console.log('Instructors', instructors);
```

Comment: It doesn't help anyone to spoon-feed beginners like this.

Comment: @slim - you are welcome to write your own non spoon feeding answer :)

Comment: @OriDori too late now. OP isn't going to do any thinking now they have something to copy/paste. Nor do beginners tend to bother upvoting, sorry.

Comment: @slim - a copy/paste user will always stay a copy/paste user no matter how hard learning you use on him. A learning user will try to understand my code, and will learn `Array#map`, and accessing object properties on the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop over your keys via:

```
for (var userGroup in users) { ... }
```

And you can get the list of a user's group via:

```
users[userGroup].forEach((item, index) => item);
```

```js
var users = {
  'Students': [ 
    { first_name:  'Michael', last_name : 'Jordan'  },
    { first_name : 'John',    last_name : 'Rosales' },
    { first_name : 'Mark',    last_name : 'Guillen' },
    { first_name : 'KB',      last_name : 'Tonel'   }
  ],
  'Instructors': [
    { first_name : 'Michael', last_name : 'Jackson' },
    { first_name : 'Martin',  last_name : 'Puryear' }
  ]
};

createLists(users, document.body, function(user) {
  return (user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name).toUpperCase();
});

function createLists(dataMap, target, formatFn) {
  for (var groupName in dataMap) {
    target.appendChild(createTextEl('H3', groupName));
    var listEl = document.createElement('OL');
    addListItems(dataMap[groupName], listEl, formatFn);
    target.appendChild(listEl);
  }
}
function addListItems(dataList, target, formatFn) {
  dataList.forEach((item, index) => target.appendChild(createTextEl('LI', formatFn(item))));
}
function createTextEl(tagName, text) {
  var el = document.createElement(tagName);
  el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
  return el;
}
```

```css
* { font-size: 0.95em; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```